# Sample C code for Canon EDSDK Liveview?

Tags: c, sample, edsdk

Is there anyone with a working piece of sample C code that implements LiveView using the Canon EDSDK?  The sample code in the documentation looks great until you get to this bit:

```
// 
// Display image 
//
```

Yup, that's it.  They don't show how to BLT an image to a window using the data retrieved from the camera.  They just say, "Display image."  Thanks, Canon.

I have hunted the Internet (including this forum), but I have yet to find a C code sample that shows how to do this.  I'm looking to avoid MFC, VB, managed code, or C#.  Surely it's possible to do this in vanilla C, right?  Vanilla C++ is fine as well.

Thanks,
FredP

Comment: Do you have MFC, VB, managed code, or C# examples?  If so, including or linking to that code here might help to figure out a C equivalent.

Comment: Sure.  Here's a V example on Stack Overflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895265/live-view-with-canon-edsdk-2-5-2-vb-net

It's a big, gnarly thing that uses a VB specific GUI element to display into.  I'm trying to BLT into a plain old HDC.

This C# one...

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/CanonSDK/message/1155

...is way simpler, but uses a "CImage" at a critical point in the code.

Comment: Gurgh, what a mess. If I had a compatible camera I might take a whack at it.  Good luck, but you might have to drink the Microsoft Kool-Aid.

Comment: Brock,

Gurgh, indeed! I guess I'll just keep hacking away at it...

Comment: Hi FredP,

Did you were able to program the C code to get the liveView? if so, can you give me a clue?
I'm just starting to program in C and I want to control my DR Xsi while learning it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are two functions that they don't tell you about:
1) `EdsGetPointer`
2) `EdsGetLength`

This will give you a pointer to the beginning of the JPEG stream and the size respectively.

Once you have this use `LibJPEG Turbo` to decompress, `Libjpeg` just isn't fast enough.

Once you decompress, you can show the image using `opencv`.

```
bool CanonCamera::downloadLiveViewImage()
{
    EdsError err = EDS_ERR_OK;
    EdsEvfImageRef image = NULL;
    EdsStreamRef stream = NULL;
    unsigned char* data = NULL;
    unsigned long size = 0;

    err = EdsCreateMemoryStream(0, &stream);

    if (err != EDS_ERR_OK) {
        cout << "Download Live View Image Error in Function EdsCreateMemoryStream: " << err << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    err = EdsCreateEvfImageRef(stream, &image);

    if (err != EDS_ERR_OK) {
        cout << "Download Live View Image Error in Function EdsCreateEvfImageRef: " << err << "\n";
        return false;

    }

    err = EdsDownloadEvfImage(cameraRef, image);

    if (err != EDS_ERR_OK) {
        cout << "Download Live View Image Error in Function EdsDownloadEvfImage: " << err << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    err = EdsGetPointer(stream, (EdsVoid**)& data);

    if (err != EDS_ERR_OK) {
        cout << "Download Live View Image Error in Function EdsGetPointer: " << err << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    err = EdsGetLength(stream, &size);

    if (err != EDS_ERR_OK) {
        cout << "Download Live View Image Error in Function EdsGetLength: " << err << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    // libjpegTurbo(data, size);
    // display RGB image in opencv

    if (stream != NULL) {
        EdsRelease(stream);
        stream = NULL;
    }

    if (image != NULL) {            
        EdsRelease(image);
        image = NULL;
    }

    data = NULL;
    return true;
}
```